# The data area passed to a system call is too small

Tags: java

When starting up an open-source Java service (Waarp, but I have the feeling this might not be connected to my problem, since it is used by other people as well), the logs show

> The data area passed to a system call is too small.

I upgraded from Java 1.8.0.71 to 1.8.0.73: no difference.

In the log I find

> -Djava.class.path=C:\Waarp\lib\WaarpR66-3.0.6.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-compress-1.10.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-daemon-1.0.15.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-net-3.4-ftp.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\ftp4j-1.7.2.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\httpclient-4.4.1.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\httpcore-4.4.1.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jackson-core-2.7.0.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jackson-dataformat-smile-2.6.2.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jackson-jaxrs-base-2.6.2.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jackson-jaxrs-smile-provider-2.6.2.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.2.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\javasysmon-0.3.6.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\jaxen-1.1.6.jar;C:\Waarp\lib\joda-time-2.9

Upgrading from one version of Waarp to another (nope, didn't work before, just trying anything I could think of), I find that the length of the `java.class.path` always seems to be around 992 characters.

I made sure `java_home` doesn't contain any spaces.

Comment: I suggest you do `-Djava.class.path=C:\Waarp\lib\*` though this appears to be an OS configuration problem. Which OS version do you have?

Comment: PS. "seems to be around 992 chars": the logging always seems to stop around 992 chars. Obviously it needs to be longer.

Comment: Jeez Peter, that was quick! Running Win10 (dirty upgrade from Win7)

Comment: In that case I would try the directory wildcard. This will not expand on the command line.

Comment: @PeterLawrey   Djava.class.path was defined as c:\waarp\lib\waarpr66-3.0.6.jar;c:\waarp\lib\*, changed it to c:\waarp\lib\\*  No difference.

Comment: In that case, it's not the cause of the problem. note you need `lib\*` not `lib*` but I suspect it's not getting that far.

Comment: Does this work for other Java programs which don't use Waarp?

Comment: my prep was a refresher course in Java (way too long ago), 2 dance lessons and a "hello world" ;-)... As I said, sorry for being a noob.  lib\* vs lib\\*: just a typo

Comment: I would start by using an IDE, and only run it externally once you have it all working.  I would also use maven or gradle as a build tool to ensure you have the right version of the libraries you need.

Comment: Ive put it all in Eclipse, which doesn't seem to have an issue with it. Since it is a service, I cant do testruns, as it doesn't have a normal "main"

Comment: It would seem the service is the source of the problem. googling the error message, the problem appeared to be related to running services.  I would ask whomever maintains the software.

Comment: isn't there a simple way of enlarging the data area? (since things seem to be limited to 992 chars) or is my thinking waarped?